# Continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can visit all real numbers only if limsup and liminf are infinite

Tags: real-analysis

During the reading of a proof there is a proposition that I can't prove it. It is the next:

A continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can visit all reals only if $\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)=\infty$ and  $\liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty}f(t)=-\infty.$

How could we prove this?

Intuitively this should be true but I don't get it. I suspect that the part if is also true but only is intuition.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Assume that $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are not both infinite and after writing down what this means use the fact that a continuous function is bounded on a closed interval.

For the "if" part, use the IVT.

---

Also, note that this result is true when your definition of $\Bbb R^+$ is $[0,\infty)$ but not if it is $(0,\infty)$, in which case $$\frac1x \sin\frac1x$$ visits every real but tends to $0$ at $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks to answer. The definition I use is $\mathbb{R}^{+}=[0,\infty).$

Comment: @Squird37 You're welcome.

Comment: I have some doubts: Following your hint, $\limsup f(t)<\infty$ or $\liminf f(t)<-\infty.$ Then there are $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\limsup f(t)=\alpha$ and $\liminf f(t)=\beta.$ For example, $\limsup f(t)=\alpha$ is the same that for every $\epsilon>0,$ there is $t_{0}\in [0,\infty]$ such that for all $s\geq t_{0}$ $|\sup f(s)-\alpha|<\epsilon.$ Similarly with $\liminf.$ Then for a compact interval, we say, $[t_{0},t^{'}]$ $f$ is bounded. Right? But I don't find the connection of this to get a contradiction.

Comment: @Squird37 The relevant compact interval will be $[0,t_0]$.

Comment: @Squird37 Also, be careful that you wrote "or" in the first sentence, and then turned it into "and" in the second sentence.

Comment: You're right @ArnaudMortier. It must be "or" in both sentences. I'll edit it. As for the other, there is a $K\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(t)|\leq K$ for all $t\in[0,t_{0}].$ As $\alpha+\epsilon$ is a number such that $f(s)\leq\alpha+\epsilon$ for all $s\geq t_{0},$ then $\max\{K,\alpha+\epsilon\}$ is upper bound of $f,$wich is a contradiction. Right?  Here $\epsilon$ is fixed.

Comment: @Squird37 Yes, you've got it.

Comment: Many thanks for the help and the patience. Would you mind if I continue asking you for the other direction?

Comment: @Squird37 I gotta go now, but the other direction is really easy.

Comment: Ok. Again thanks a lot!